# Roslyn Blazor WASM: Can't Create A Metadata Reference To An Assembly Without Location

Tags: c#, blazor, roslyn, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to evaluate very simple formulas at runtime using Roslyn in a Blazor environment.
Here is an example:

```
ScriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.AddImports("System");
var formula = "20 + 10";
var res = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(formula, ScriptOptions);
```

Even though the code is very basic (no external libraries needed), the EvaluateAsync method throws the following:

```
Can't Create A Metadata Reference To An Assembly Without Location
```

I have tried [this](https://github.com/andersstorhaug/SingleFileScripting/blob/main/SingleFileScripting/Program.cs) approach to load assemblies but the `Assembly.TryGetRawMetadata` method fails on my mac fails with a  `NotImplementedException`

Any ideas on what I'm missing?